# If $f(x) = 3x^2 + 4x + 5$, what must the value of $k$ equal so that the graph of $f(x – k)$ will be symmetric to the y-axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have been told that to solve this problem, we can complete the square to get $f(x) = 3\left(x + \frac{2}{3}\right)^2 + c$ for a constant $c$. Then $f(x - \frac{2}{3}) = 3x^2 + c$ which is symmetric about the y-axis, so $k = \frac{2}{3}$.

But can someone explain the logic as to why this is true. Maybe add graphs and explain what the varying values of $k$ change and how is it symmetric at $\frac{2}{3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function $f(x)$ represents a parabola with axis parallel to the y-axis and to have the function symmetric with respect to the y-axis, you need to shift the axis of the parabola so that it coincides with the y-axis and it looks like the y-axis has bifurcated your graph. That is what you have done by shifting the origin by k units.

In short, your parabola or your function must have the general form $(x-a)^2=4r(y-k)$ or, $f(x-k)=A(x-a^2)+c$ like you have got.

As for graphs, I have both of them. See the difference yourself.
[image]
[image]

I hope I am clear which one is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f(x-k)$. For $g$ to be symmetric about the $y-$axis, you need $g(x)=g(-x)$. This implies we need to have
$$f(x-k)=f(-x-k).$$
Upon simplifying this you will get
$$x(-3k+2)=0.$$
Since this should hold for all values of $x$, therefore $k=\frac{2}{3}$.

**Note:** The basic idea is that the coefficient of the $x$ term has to be zero for it be symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$f(x-k)=3(x-k)^2+4(x-k)+5$$$$=3x^2+2(2-3k)x+3k^2-4k+5$$
For the function $f(x-k)$ to be symmetrical about the y-axis, it should satisfy $f(-(x-k))=f(x-k)$ which is possible only when the coefficient of $x$ is $0$ hence, we have $$2(2-3k)=0\implies \color{red}{k=\frac{2}{3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can write f(x-k) as:

f(x-k) = 3(x-k)^2 +4(x-k)+5

For f(x-k) to be symmetric about y axis, we need to fulfil the following condition:

f(x-k)=f(-x-k)

f(-x-k) = 3(-x-k)^2+4(-x-k)+5
12xk-8x=0

3xk-2x=0

k =2/3